# How to get the value of a text box using jQuery's prop function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

i am trying to get a value of some text box but its not working , more over the `prop` function isnt working also . All i want is to enable the elements when the checkbox is checked and then show the value inside the textbox in alert window

Link to jsfiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/k0cfj48L/5/

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
 <td class="td" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <input type="text" class="chkEdit" disabled /></td>

 <td class="td" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <input type="checkbox" class="chkView" value="Edit" /></td>

 <td class="td" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> <input type="submit" class="chkUpdate" onclick="check();" disabled /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('change','.chkView',function(){
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {          
        $(row).find('.chkEdit,.chkUpdate').prop("disabled",false); 
        //var x = $(row).find('.chkEdit').val();   
    }else{
        $(row).find('.chkEdit,.chkUpdate').prop("disabled",true);     
    }
});

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function check()    {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var x =$(row).find('.chkEdit').val();
    alert(x);
    return ;
}
```

The jsfiddle is edited the enable function is working but i still cant get the alert

Comment: Include jQuery in your fiddle using the dropdown in the top left corner. Check your console (F12) for errors.

Comment: @Dom jquery is there in the fiddle or maybe i did not get your point

Comment: @amol check again your own link. There's no selected jQuery library.

Comment: Also make sure to check "no wrap - in body" or "DOM ready" instead of "onLoad" in the dropdown.  Otherwise it will not recognize any functions declared - http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/k0cfj48L/4/

Comment: @Dom... it will recoginze if the jQuery functions are wrapped in DOM ready (which they are not :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan my mistake, DOM ready will also work in this case.

Comment: @amol I clicked your jsFiddle link but no jQuery on the right panel was selected. You should learn to select your library and than update your fiddle. But never mind I've added the code in your question for future visitors to see it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/k0cfj48L/6/)***

in your HTML pass the `this` reference as fn argument!

```
onclick="check(this);"
```

<sup>**Disclaimer of liability**: I'm not suggesting to use inline JS at all - read further!</sup>

than in jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change','.chkView', function(){  
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.chkEdit, .chkUpdate').prop("disabled", !this.checked);    
});
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function check(el){ // `el` is the `this` element argument you've passed in HTML
    var x = $(el).closest('tr').find('.chkEdit').val();
    return alert( x );
}
```

---

Also instead of using lnline JS (inside HTML) which makes programmers life really hard,
do it all in JS! ***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/k0cfj48L/9/)***

```
$('.chkUpdate').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = $(this).closest('tr').find('.chkEdit').val();
    alert( x );
});
```

**Note** that if your **table is created dynamically** you might want to use the dynamic event delegation like:

```
$('.someNotDynamicParent').on("click", ".chkUpdate", function(e){
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/k0cfj48L/2/

I have fixed your fiddle.

1) JQuery was not included, so '$' in $(document).ready() was not defined.

2) I changed the JS to be included in the head so your check function is read as defined on execution of the page.

3) Your check function is not being instantiated directly within an event, so $(this) does nothing, rather is just a window reference.  I incldued a proper selection of the textarea, but I'd consider using IDs or adding a jQuery event on the submit button and then finding a sibling:

```
$(document).on('change','.chkView',function(){
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {          
        $(row).find('.chkEdit,.chkUpdate').prop("disabled",false); 
        //var x = $(row).find('.chkEdit').val();   
    }
    else
    {
        $(row).find('.chkEdit,.chkUpdate').prop("disabled",true);     
    }
});

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function check()    
  {
      var x = $('.chkEdit').val();
       alert(x);
       return ;
  }
```

Comment: thanks man , but `var x = $('.chkEdit')` will become hard code ..can it be made dynamic using functions like closest or find ...this question is a part of some bigger issue which requires some dynamic  content..thanks in advance

Comment: Correct.  I was working on a more elegant dynamic solution, but Roko has beat me to it ;)